# AngularJS: Using ng-messages with ng-min

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I'm working with an input field with `type="number"` and I specifically want to use `ng-min="0"`. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong, but I don't see any message when I enter a value below zero into my field with my current implementation.

I did make sure to include angular messages like so: `angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages'])`.

My code:

```
<admin-form name="formName">
  <admin-field>
    <input 
      name="formName" 
      ng-model="$ctrl.model.whatever" 
      type="number" 
      min="0" />
    <div ng-messages="userForm.formName.$error" style="color: maroon" role="alert">
        <ng-message when="min">Value cannot be below 0</ng-message>
    </div>
```

A working plunkr is available here: https://plnkr.co/edit/PUT7r1hNbJrjHDF0vhJd

Comment: I recognize that I could do this with some `ng-if`s but that's messy and I shouldn't have to do that. Plus I spent all day figuring out how to include `ngMessages` in the app that I work on so I intend on using it :^)

Answer (score 2):

The PLNKR used obsolete libraries. With updated libraries, it works:

```js
angular.module('myapp', ['ngMessages'])
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
 
 <body ng-app="myapp">
    <form name="myForm">
      <label>Enter your number:</label><br>
      <input type="number" name="myNumber" ng-model="num"
                ng-min="0" role="alert">
      
      <div ng-messages="myForm.myNumber.$error" style="color:red">
        <div ng-message="min">Your field value is lesser minimum value</div>
      </div>
      
    </form>
 </body>
```

Comment: The way you're doing it works here, but I can't make it work in PLUNKR. Also, I'm using `ngMessages` 1.6.1 in my app but I don't think updating it to it's current version will do anything because I looked at the changelogs for it and there's nothing about making it work with `ngMin`. Any ideas?